# No GraphQL endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I followd this tutorial to learn how to use GraphQl with Annotations: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-graphql-spqr however, i dont have any entry point with /graphql and localhost:8080/graphiql does not wor kas well what did i do wrong?

The Service:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@GraphQLApi
public class VehicleService implements IVehicleService
{
    // == fields ==
    private final IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;

    // == methods ==
    public void SaveVehicle(VehicleRequest vehicleRequest)
    {
        VehicleModel model = VehicleModel.builder()
                .Works(WorksToWorkModels(vehicleRequest.Works()))
                .Type(vehicleRequest.Type())
                .Number(vehicleRequest.Number())
                .Status(vehicleRequest.Status())
                .Stand(vehicleRequest.Stand())
                .Priority(vehicleRequest.Priority())
                .build();
        model.getWorks().stream().forEach(element -> element.setVehicleModel(model));
        _vehicleRepository.save(model);
    }

    @GraphQLQuery(name="GetAllVehicles")
    public List<VehicleModel> GetAlLVehicles()
    {
        return _vehicleRepository.findAll();
    }

    // == private methods ==
    private List<WorkModel> WorksToWorkModels(List<WorkRequest> request)
    {
        return request.stream().map(work -> WorkModel.builder()
                .Description(work.Description())
                .ResponsiblePerson(work.ResponsiblePerson())
                .Priority(work.Priority())
                .build()
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

As they state in point 4.2 i do not need any Resolver class anymore and the Controller should be autogenerated as well or did i understand anything wrong? Why is it not working?

Comment: For simplicity i have made my git repository public so you can downlaod rthe project and maybe look at it more easily: https://github.com/WoistdasNiveau/OegegEtdBackend.git